# Parsing JSON output file

Tags: python, json

Hi a learner in python I have written code the extracts a son file from a sports website.

The code is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2022-08-01/sportsbet-pakenham-synthetic/sectionaltimes/race-2.json?"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

and the output looks like this (small portion)

```
sectionaltimes_callback({"Horses":[{"Comment":"Slow Out 1 Lengths , got back 2nd last off tardy start 8 Lengths 800m, still mile off them getting widest from the corner, charged home last 200m for eye catching second spot # powered home widest","FinalPosition":2,"FinalPositionAbbreviation":"2nd","FullName":"Ameerati","SaddleNumber":12,"HorseUrl":"/horses/ameerati","SilkUrl":"//cdn.silks.racing.com/bb/114031.png","Trainer":"Robbie Griffiths & Mathew de Kock","TrainerUrl":"/trainers/robbie-griffiths","Jockey":"P.M.Moloney","JockeyUrl":"/jockeys/patrick-moloney","SectionalTimes":[{"Distance":"1200m","Position":11,"Time":"1:11.43","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"1000m","Position":11,"Time":"59.29","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"800m","Position":11,"Time":"46.95","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"600m","Position":11,"Time":"34.77","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"400m","Position":11,"Time":"22.71","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"200m","Position":4,"Time":"11.45","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"Finish","Position":2,"Time":"","AvgSpeed":0.0}],"SplitTimes":[{"Distance":"1200m-1000m","Position":11,"Time":"12.14","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"1000m-800m","Position":11,"Time":"12.34","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"800m-600m","Position":11,"Time":"12.18","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"600m-400m","Position":11,"Time":"12.06","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"400m-200m","Position":11,"Time":"11.26","AvgSpeed":0.0},{"Distance":"200m-Finish","Position":4,"Time":"11.45","AvgSpeed":0.0}],"StartPosition":0,"BarrierNumber":12,"RaceTime":"","TimeVarToWinner":0.0,"BeatenMargin":0.0,"DistanceRun":0,"DistanceVarToWinner":"","SixHundredMetresTime":"34.77","TwoHundredMetresTime":"11.45","Early":0.0,"Mid":0.0,"Late":0.0,"OverallPeakSpeed":0.0,"PeakSpeedLocation":null,"OverallAvgSpeed":0.0,"DistanceFromRail":0.0},
```

The help I would appreciate now is what do I do to put this in a format that I can open in excel

Comment: That's JSONP, not JSON. It has a function call `sectionaltimes_callback(...)` wrapped around the JSON. You need to remove that before calling `json.loads()`

Comment: So would it be possible for you to expand on your comment a bit more because I am a novice finding my way by watching youtube videos and reading this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

def race_data_to_xslxs(url, fname):
    # get data
    data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text[24:-1])

    # create dataframes
    dfs = {}
    singulars = pd.DataFrame()
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            dfs[k] = pd.DataFrame(v)
        else:
            singulars[k] = [v]
    dfs = {'summary': singulars, **dfs}

    # create workbook
    wb = Workbook()
    for k, df in dfs.items():
        # create sheet
        wsx = wb.create_sheet(title=k)
        rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)
        for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
            for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
                wsx.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=str(value))
    del wb['Sheet']
    # write excel file
    wb.save(filename=fname)

url = "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2022-08-01/sportsbet-pakenham-synthetic/sectionaltimes/race-2.json?"
path = 'fname.xlsx'
race_data_to_xslxs(url=url, fname=path)
```

Comment: So to totally understand your solution is this coded added to existing code or replacing?

Comment: @Learner it is self-contained

Comment: Completed but I note that it is sending data to multiple worksheets I would like all the data to be populated in one worksheet with headings across the top and lines of data running down the page. Any chance you could provide a different layout format option

Answer (score 1):

The API is returning JSONP, not JSON. This is JSON wrapped in a call to a callback function, which can be used by browsers without violating the same-origin rule. You need to remove that function call before parsing it as JSON.

```
import re
import json

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
json_string = re.sub(r'^sectionaltimes_callback\((.*)\)$', r'\1', response)
data = json.loads(json_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/racevic.static/2022-08-01/sportsbet-pakenham-synthetic/sectionaltimes/race-2.json?"
response = requests.get(url)
json.loads(response.text.split("(", 1)[1].strip(")"))
```